# After delete previous files and place new files in wwwroot folder, getting 404/403 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, web-deployment

After delete previous files and place new files in website folder inside wwwroot , getting 404/403 error in IIS 10.

There are a lots of .compiled and .dll files in BIN folder. I deleted the whole BIN folder and other folders and then copied all folders and files produced after published from Visual Studio.

But after place new folder and files, I am getting 404/403 errors.

I couldn't find the actual reason for this error. Every file is in right place.

Comment: What kind of 403/404? Use FRT to capture more information about them, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What's the sub-status code of 403 and 404 error ? Since 404 and 403 are totally different symptom,  you have to post more detailed including request url ,sample code for each error. We could help only when we get enough details and error message.